# Swift: How to override a method for a scrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, overriding

I'm trying to override the **touchesShouldCancel** method for a subclass of a scrollview.

This is my subclass code:

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        print("Works")
        return false
    }
}
```

I have made a scrollview of this class and it scrolls it just doesn't ever print "works". I would like to add some functionality to this but it's never being called. According to the apple documentation:

'The scroll view calls this method just after it starts sending tracking messages to the content view.'

This makes me believe the method should be called whenever I am scrolling and I can't figure out why it's not. Cheers if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview):

> Because a scroll view has no scroll bars, it must know whether a touch signals an intent to scroll versus an intent to track a subview in the content. To make this determination, it temporarily intercepts a touch-down event by starting a timer and, before the timer fires, seeing if the touching finger makes any movement. If the timer fires without a significant change in position, the scroll view sends tracking events to the touched subview of the content view. If the user then drags their finger far enough before the timer elapses, the scroll view cancels any tracking in the subview and performs the scrolling itself. Subclasses can override the touchesShouldBegin(_:with:in:), isPagingEnabled, and touchesShouldCancel(in:) methods (which are called by the scroll view) to affect how the scroll view handles scrolling gestures.

Do this experiment.

1. Add a subview to your scrollview that intercepts touches (think UIButton, not UILabel).
2. Make sure your content is actually scrollable
3. Press down on the button and wait for just a moment, then start sliding your finger.

   - When you tap down on the scroll view and start dragging right away, it assumes you want to scroll the scroll view and not interact with the button.
   - However when you do that slight pause, it wants to determine if you're trying to interact with the scroll view or with the button.
4. `touchesShouldCancel` will then fire.